# Firestore -> Does the snapshots manage the app cache?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore in my mobile app.

I have been looking for ways to reduce the number of readings that I will do to build the screens in my application.

I was thinking about starting a snapshot for each collection that I have and want to know if the snapshots themselves handle the cache of the app or if I should make a read to save in the cache(which I know will work).

I planned to use the snapshots to manage this and then use the collection to read the data using the cache as the only source.

How could I make it work?

If more information is needed, ask for it in the comments.

I didn't do any try by this time, was just thinking about it.

Comment: A snapshot is just a bunch of data, with some convenience methods around it. But yes ([when enabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)) Firestore automatically caches recently read data, and will [return the data from the cache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#listen_to_offline_data) when available and/or [requested](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#get_offline_data).

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e) will help.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been looking for ways to reduce the number of readings that I will do to build the screens in my application.

There are two ways in which you can reduce the number of reads:

1. Call [Query#limit(n)](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/limit.html) to reduce the number of documents you read. Preferably, only read a number of documents that fit into the screen, and nothing more.
2. Implement [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) so you can load the data in smaller chunks.

> I was thinking about starting a snapshot for each collection that I have and want to know if the snapshots themselves handle the cache of the app or if I should make a read to save in the cache(which I know will work).

For Android and iOS, [offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence) is enabled by default. For the web, offline persistence is disabled by default. To enable persistence, call the enablePersistence method. So there is no need to implement your own caching mechanism.

If you want to read the data only from the cache, please note that this is perfectly possible. You should pass the [GetOptions](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/GetOptions-class.html) object as the argument to the [Query#get()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/get.html) call. In this way, you can choose to use a [Source](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Source.html) that can be either the `cache` or the `server`.

Comment: Hey Guilherme. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?